# Centering code listings in tabular

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, minted

I'm inserting code listings using mint into a tabular, but the text and listings in corresponding columns aren't centered. How do I center them?

Here's my table code:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{| c | m{12cm} | m{6cm} | m{6cm} |}
    \hline
    Clone Type & Definition & Sample piece 1 & Sample piece 2 \\ \hline

    1 &
    Identical code fragments except for variations in whitespace (may be also
    variations in layout) and comments. & \begin{minted}
    [
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    ]
    {c}
    if (a >= b)
    { c = d + b; }
    else c = d - a;
    \end{minted}
    & \begin{minted}
    [
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    ]
    {c}
    if (a >= b)
    { c = d + b; }
    else c = d - a;
    \end{minted}
    \\ \hline
\end{center}
```

Comment: If I make your code compilable the minted listings are centered. Please do not forget ending the tabular environment.